# progam stop responding after std::getline am is there a mistake in the code?

Tags: c++

a part of the progam code is below after i add the name(nome) and press enter the progam closes i already tried using gets didn`t work either

```
aux1 = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no)+1);
printf("\n\nDigite numero a ser inserido: ");
gets(auxitem);
aux1->numero = atoi(auxitem);
printf("\n\nDigite o nome do contato ser inserido: ");
std::getline(std::cin, aux1->nome);
aux1->esq = aux1->dir = (struct no*) NULL;
 if (raiz == (struct no *) NULL)
raiz= aux1;
```

Comment: `gets` is so bad that it's since been removed from C++. `getline` is the way to go to read a line of input.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `no` is a class with a member named `nom`, whose type is some instantiation of `std::basic_string`, such as `std::string` (it would have to be in order for that call to `std::getline` to compile). That being the case, `no` is not a POD type, and in order to use it, you need to construct it. `aux1` does not point to a constructed `no` object. It just points to raw memory allocated by malloc. So you are calling `std::getline` with something which is not a valid constructed string object. You need to either construct an object after you call `malloc`.

```
aux1 = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no)+1);
new (aux1) no(/* constructor arguments here */);
...
// later, when you're done with the object
aux1->~no();
free(aux1);
```

Or allocate your object with a `new` expression, which will handle both the allocation and construction.

```
aux1 = new no(/* constructor arguments here */);
...
// later, when you're done with the object
delete aux1;
```